# Вопрос по поводу цитирования

Tags: цитата

Бывают ситуации, когда при цитировании через кавычки требуется опустить целое предложение и продолжить цитировать. Какой знак нужно использовать? <...> (Троеточие в кавычках)? Или просто троеточие? Или указать в скокбах, какие предложение пропускаются (предложение 57,58)?

Answer (score 3):

Интересно, что в справочнике Розенталя в разделе "Знаки препинания при цитатах" вообще нет ни слова об угловых скобках.
[Многоточие при цитатах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=165#pp165)

Интересно, что у Лопатина в ПАС угловые скобки используются только в одном случае:

> [§ 144.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139) При сокращении цитаты, уже имеющей многоточия, выполняющие те или иные свойственные им функции, многоточие, поставленное автором, цитирующим текст, указывающее на сокращение цитаты, заключается в угловые скобки: *В дневнике Л. Н. Толстого читаем: «Она не может отречься от своего чувства ‹...›. У нее, как у всех женщин, первенствует чувство, и всякое изменение происходит, может быть, независимо от разума, в чувстве... Может быть, Таня права, что это само собой понемногу пройдет ‹...›»*.

Поэтому можно сделать интересный вывод: если при цитировании текста, в котором нет многоточия, вы его [многоточие] поставите на месте пропуска одного или двух предложений, то такое оформление не будет считаться ошибкой.

"Грамота" же утверждает следующее:

> **Вопрос № 307465.** ...Однозначно указывает на купюру многоточие в угловых скобках, но его рекомендовано использовать для обозначения пропущенного предложения или нескольких предложений. Обычно потребность в таком обозначении возникает в книжной речи. <...>
>
> **Вопрос № 290167.** ...некоторые авторы последовательно заключают многоточие, указывающее на сокращение цитаты, в угловые скобки <...>. При этом отметим, что в «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина и Л. Э. Чельцовой такой знак рекомендуется использовать, только если из цитаты исключается фрагмент, состоящий из целого предложения (одного или нескольких).
>
> **Вопрос № 270349.** ...Многоточие в угловых скобках заменяет опущенный при цитировании текст из одного или нескольких предложений: *Предложение цитаты. <...> Предложение цитаты.* Пропуск нескольких слов и словосочетаний обозначается просто многоточием.

Я обычно использую многоточие в угловых скобках при цитировании словарных статей, при пропуске абзаца или нескольких строф стихотворения.

P. S. *Предложение 57, 58* — нет, такие "добавки" при цитировании не нужны.

[Угловые скобки](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B#:%7E:text=%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85,%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9.) ("Грамота")

Answer (score 1):

Это не кавычки, а угловые скобки.
"Грамота" пишет:

> Пропуск нескольких предложений, одного или нескольких абзацев принято обозначать многоточием в угловых скобках.